# What settings to use for Kafka ISR?

Tags: apache-kafka

running Kafka 0.11 as a 3 broker cluster. It's running as a container inside mesos.

The cluster is processing million of messages every day with out a hitch but once in a while (over a year) some of the brokers get out of sync and in this case it got out of sync on a low volume period.

The easy fix is to just reboot the broker and it gets back in sync. But obviously I would like to avoid this.

- replica.lag.time.max.ms is set to 10000
- min.insync.replicas = 2 (all topics default to)

Each broker is configured as:

- 3 CPUS
- 24GB to the container
- 5GB to the JVM

Comment: Not enough information is here... What is the acks setting of your producers? What are the topics' min.insync.replicas value?

Comment: I updated my question, but basically all my topics default to 2 in sync replicas. And the producers, since I cannot go through all of them, I would guess are using various ack settings.